# Gnome Screenshot utilty is using 100% of the CPU and and not saving rectangular window, just entire screen!

Tags: 20.04, gnome-screenshot

- I'm using Ubuntu `20.04`, after some days the gnome screenshot app is not parsing the dialog to save the images, and not saving them automatically.
- I tried to remove it and install it again, but that didn't solve the problem.
- Also when I open it `/usr/bin/gnome-screenshot --gapplication-service` starts to consume resources `cpu` without parsing the dialog!
- can you please tell me how to solve this problem? thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried restarting GNOME Alt+F2 then r

Comment: @24601 yes, it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Please [edit] your question with details of the Storage Settings for Screenshot Tool.

Comment: @24601 how can I get the storage settings of the Screenshot please? because I'm new to ubuntu, and I don't know how to get them.

Comment: If you have the Screenshot Tool on your System Tray (top bar) then left click and select `Settings`. Then go to the `Storage` tab. Otherwise go to https://extensions.gnome.org/local/ in your browser, select `Installed Extensions` and select the configure tool for this extension from there.

Comment: @24601 I added a screenshot using `shift` + `PrtScn`, and looked into the `Installed Extensions` didn't find screenshot extension!

Comment: Ah, ok. That is not GNOME extension `Screenshot tool` but the screenshot utility installed by default. They are different things.

Comment: I've just used it to save a screenshot and it worked fine in v20.04..2 v 3.36.0 of the tool. Have you set the folder where you want the shot to be saved and does it exist? Mine saves to `Pictures` by default.